# DateTime.ToString pattern to preserve even the smallest part

Tags: .net, datetime, tostring

I need to store exact `DateTime` as a filename, and restore it when needed.
Pattern `dd_MM_yyyy hh_mm_ss_ff tt` doesn't seem to match the original date (after using `DateTime.ParseExact`, so I believe part of the date is lost upon conversion. Is ticks the smallest part of DateTime? How to save it to string as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ticks represent the smallest measurement on a DateTime.

```
String filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt";
```

Comment: Does it return a total number of ticks, or ticks part of datetime only?

Comment: Ticks total to that DateTime value

Comment: Does that mean I can name the file with just "DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()" and ignore the rest?

Comment: @Sphynx Edited answer; using for a filename, no need to call ToString() in that instance.

Comment: Downvoting because this doesn't answer the question which is `to preserve even the smallest part`. It doesn't mean we want to get rid of all other parts. It means we want to keep **everything**

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL I'm not seeing anything regarding preservation in the question. This is what the question states... _is ticks the smallest part of DateTime?_ and what drove my response at the time. Furthermore, given the OP accepted it as the answer, apparently it met their needs given the context of the ask.

Comment: @AaronMcIver well, preservation is both stated in the title `to preserve even the smallest part` and in the text right under `I need to store exact DateTime as a filename` which as it says **store the exact DateTime** meaning he didn't want to keep only the ticks but the entire DateTime. You posted your answer one day before the other one so OP accepted it and then didn't change it afterwards. However the other answer with more upvotes better answers the question. Yours is not

Answer (score 6):

I believe you want to reliably time-stamp your log file. Well, the format you provide will not be reliable, i.e. it will look different depending on Thread's CurrentCulture value.

I would recommend using something like "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF" if you want to have precise and reliable time stamp.